# Issues using NetworkServer.Spawn with Unity and Mirror-Networking

Tags: unity, c#, unity-networking, spawning

I am using Mirror to handle the networking aspect

When I spawn an object on the network, I Instantiate it on the server and then use NetworkServer.Spawn to notify all clients to spawn the object.

However, when this object is eventually spawned on the client side, it seems to be spawned at the wrong position for a few seconds and then corrected itself and move to the correct position as is reflected by the server. Is there something I am not doing? Is this normal?

Also I noticed if I changed the Network Sync Mode to 0, then it will only spawn in the wrong spot for a split second.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Mirror;

public class EnemySpawner : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public uint theId;
    public int maxNumEnemies;
    public int spawnDelay;
    public GameObject enemyToSpawn;
    float curSpawnTime;
    BoxCollider2D boxColl;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public override void OnStartServer()
    {
        curSpawnTime = spawnDelay;
        boxColl = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (!isServer) return;
        theId = netId;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!isServer) return; 
        if (transform.childCount < maxNumEnemies && curSpawnTime <= 0.0f)
        {
            Vector2 spawnPoint = new Vector2(Random.Range(boxColl.bounds.min.x, boxColl.bounds.max.x),Random.Range(boxColl.bounds.min.y, boxColl.bounds.max.y));
            curSpawnTime = spawnDelay;
            SpawnEnemies(spawnPoint,netId);
        } else
        {
            curSpawnTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    [Server]
    void SpawnEnemies(Vector2 spawnPoint, uint theId)
    {
        GameObject gobj = Instantiate(enemyToSpawn, new Vector2(60.7f,1.3f), Quaternion.identity);
        gobj.GetComponent<EnemyController>().parentNetId = netId;
        NetworkServer.Spawn(gobj);
    }
}
```

The way I've organized things, in the hierarchy I have:

```
Enemies
   Area1
      Spider(Clone)
      Spider(Clone)
```

Area1 has the EnemySpawner script.  The spider is registered a spawnable prefab.
Both Area1 and the Spider have a NetworkIdentity with no boxes checked.
Additionally, the Spider has a NetworkTransform and NetworkAnimator.

Answer (score 0):

As of what I have experienced before, a lag for like a split second is pretty normal.
This is bound to happen if you're trying to run your server on a work desktop or on a local machine. If you wanna spawn stuff really quickly without that displacement in the start, you would need a really good internet and dedicated server, based on how many players you have playing on that server at the moment and the number of objects that you have network transform attached to and want to keep those gameobject positions synced over the server.